# Application is only storing data when I enter the score window

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a game which stores it's high scores in a SQLite database but it only stores the scores when I open the window in my app which shows the said scores, if I play 2 games in a row and then open the high scores window it will only show the later score. So I tried to make a method which I can call from the main class but I get null reference error. This below is my Highscore class which saves the scores. How can I make it so it saves the scores even without opening "highscores" window ?

```
public class highscores extends Activity {
private ListView scorebox1;
private ListView scorebox2;
private ListView scorebox3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscores);
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
    scorebox1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorebox1);
    scorebox2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorebox2);
    scorebox3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorebox3);



    // Create database helper
    DBHandler mDbHelper = new DBHandler(this);

    // Gets the database in write mode
    SQLiteDatabase db2 = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Create a ContentValues object where column names are the keys,
    // and pet attributes from the editor are the values.
    if(difficutlyFrSQL != ""){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                                 
    values.put(DBHandler.KEY_TIME, difficutlyFrSQL);                            
    values.put(DBHandler.KEY_DIFFICULTY, difficutlyFrSQL2);
    long newRowId = db2.insert(DBHandler.TABLE_DETAIL, null, values);           

    // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the insertion was successful
    if (newRowId == -1) {
        // If the row ID is -1, then there was an error with insertion.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error with saving test score", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, the insertion was successful and we can display a toast with the row ID.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test score saved with row id: " + newRowId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        difficutlyFrSQL = "";
    }
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all scores..");                                                                         
    ArrayList<String>ar3=new ArrayList<>();                                                                             
    ar3=db.getAllScores(3);
    Collections.sort(ar3);
    Collections.reverse(ar3);
    ArrayAdapter<String>ap3=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ar3);
        scorebox1.setAdapter(ap3);
    ArrayList<String>ar2=new ArrayList<>();
    ar2=db.getAllScores(2);
    Collections.sort(ar2);
    Collections.reverse(ar2);
    ArrayAdapter<String>ap2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ar2);
    scorebox2.setAdapter(ap2);
    ArrayList<String>ar1=new ArrayList<>();
    ar1=db.getAllScores(1);
    Collections.sort(ar1);
    Collections.reverse(ar1);
    ArrayAdapter<String>ap1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ar1);
    scorebox3.setAdapter(ap1);
}
}
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious that since you save your score on the `highscores` activity and only one insert is done in the database that you will only get the later score? You have to save the score in your game activity when the player reaches game over for example. BUT you provide no code for it, update your question with all the involved code if you want someone to help you.

Comment: but even if I make it so that it stores the scores somewhere in main activity it will still require the player to go to highscores window before he exits the game in order to memorize the scores. I want to make it to save them in the SQLite database even without opening highscores. Can I make the whole class highscores something like a method and call it once the game is over ?

Comment: Why don't you call the save to database from your main activity? You already have this code inside high scores activity just move it to the main activity. the high scores activity should only display the scores not saving them.